# Could a blind person with a death note exchange half their life to see again?

Tags: death-note

One of the rules of the death note says that if someone makes the shinigami eyes deal they will have excellent vision regardless of their previous vision.

The rule in question, (listed under the Death Note Wiki as "How to Use: XXI"):

> "Those with the eye power of the god of death will have the eyesight
>   of over 3.6 in the human measurement, regardless of their original
>   eyesight."

Could Light or any of the other characters in the series have cured a blind person with this rule? It seems to be a brilliant way to avoid suspicion and get a true ally to cure a blind person in exchange for half of their life and abuse their gratefulness to make them kill people for you, and who's going to suspect a blind man?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the wording of the rules of deathnote and the way the "eyes of Shinigami" are explained in the anime this scenario seems plausible.

However, as I've said many times in such questions this is meaningless speculation since either scenario is plausible and the rules of DN leave room for speculation. So other than just saying this scenario is possible and saying that some of our better fanfic writers picking this up as a possible plot point Idk what else to add.

However, to add to the "suspicion" on a blind man scenario. There are many ways this would be a bad idea.

- Suddenly a blind person is cured. Publicity, DN user is exposed. Someone else may have seen them together
- It is not so easy to hide that you are not blind. Plenty of involuntary actions, such as dodging, moving hands etc give away the fact you're not blind. It would be much tougher for a blind person who has healed to hide these signs.

So on surface it may seem a good idea, but it has its own pitfalls, pros and cons just as another. Also the blind person will lose his sight the moment he gives up ownership of the DN. I would like to think that the KIRA will kill to get the Notebook back.